# Auto refresh canvas element to plot data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have the code to auto fetch data from my phpmyadmin database and display it on the webpage which is done on the first script tag. The next converts the data that has been fetched to the correct format for plotting. The draw function in the last script tag is the function that needs to repeat every 1-2 seconds however I cannot get the function to repeat.
Can anyone suggest some code or tutorials please.

```html
<script type="text/javascript"> //this automaticall gets the data
  
  $(document).ready(function() {
   setInterval(function(){
    $('#show').load('load.php');
   }, 3000);
  });

 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript"> //this converts to the correct format
   var xcoor = <?php echo json_encode($xcoordinate); ?>;
   var ycoor = <?php echo json_encode($ycoordinate); ?>;
   var xlength = xcoor.length
 </script>

 <canvas id="tutorial" width="500" height="500"></canvas>


  
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function draw() {
         var canvas = document.getElementById('tutorial');
         if (canvas.getContext) {
           var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

       var bw = 400;
    // Box height
    var bh = 400;
    // Padding
    var p = 0;
    var boxsize = 5;

    ctx.beginPath();
    for (var x = 0; x <= bw; x += boxsize) {
        ctx.moveTo(0.5 + x + p, p);
        ctx.lineTo(0.5 + x + p, bh + p);
       }

       for (var x = 0; x <= bh; x += boxsize) {
           ctx.moveTo(p, 0.5 + x + p);
           ctx.lineTo(bw + p, 0.5 + x + p);
     }


        //this plots the data
     var xlength1 = xlength - 3;
       for (var x = 0; x<= xlength; x+=1){
        ctx.fillRect((xcoor[x]*20),(x*10),5,5);
        if (x > xlength1){
         ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        }
     

       ctx.stroke();
    }
         }
     }
     draw();
    </script>
```

Comment: Where is your jQuery CDN import?

Comment: Its at the top of the page, I didn't include it in the code but here it is:<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>